# How to create a dynamic 2D character array using operator new?

Tags: c++, string, new-operator

I want to use new operator to create an array of strings. But I am not able to figure out how to do this using a single command.

I can do this using `calloc`  like `arg = (char*) calloc(totalarg_velanalyze, 5);`

But I have been told to use `new` instead.

Comment: Add the language tag, is it C++?

Comment: If your school teaches you arrays and `new` before `std::vector` and `std::string`, consider running away while screaming loudly.

Comment: Is the purpose of this exercise to allocate N number of M-length fixed char buffers? When you say "string" to a room full of C++ engineers, `std::string` leaps to the forefront. When you say "array", either `std::array<>` or `std::vector<>` likewise leap to the head of the line. Clarify the intention and your attempt at using `operator new` (failure is an option) and we'll see what we can do for you.

Comment: Thanks for responding.
My purpose is to create a 2d character array to store strings
like char a[10][]={"abc","def".......};
But I want to do this dynamic as I dont know the size 10 in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If the intention is to allocate a contiguous array of fixed-length char arrays (what you call a 2D char array), the syntax isn't terrible. The row width must be a compile-time constant, but the number of rows can be arbitrary. Given some arbitrary primary dimension `n` and some fixed size row-width `M`, you would do it like this:

```
char (*p)[M] = new char[n][M];
```

and delete it like this when no longer needed:

```
delete [] p;
```

Access to any buffer `i` from 0..n-1 is done as:

```
p[i]
```

such as copying "foo" to the third row:

```
std::strcpy(p[2], "foo");
```

just as you would with a regular fixed array of arrays.

That said, I would advise that unless you have a compelling reason to do  otherwise (some specific odd legacy API or some such) that you use the standard library containers. They really are the cats whiskers. At a *minimum* you should [use smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one), as [raw pointers should not own resources](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1).

Hope it helps (particularly heeding the last paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ its best to use vector of strings.

You can declare it as

```
vector<string> varname(length);
varname[0]="xyz";
varname[1]="dfg";
```

or you can let the length be unspecified and add elements using `push_back();`

Comment: To clarify, if you don't supply `length` to the constructor, then the length starts off as `0`; and in both cases you can extend it by doing `push_back`

Comment: I would like to use various functions like strmcmp etc. 
char a[]="abc";
strcmp(a,varname[0]);
How is that possible using vectors.

Comment: @user3649296 You are supposed to write `a == varname[0]`, but you could also write `strcmp(a, varname[0].c_str())`. A C++ `string` is not a `char *`, but can give you a `char *` with `.c_str()`. They seem to be teaching you C instead of C++. Those languages have different ways of doing things and you are doing it the C way in a C++ program which is considered bad.